# Keep forked process alive if parent/child exits abnormally (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, process, exec, fork

I am trying to execute another command line process in parallel with the current process. However, I realize that the command line program sometimes abnormally exits, and that kills my main program as well.

```
// MAIN PROGRAM
pid = fork();
char *argv[] = { stuff.. };
if (pid == 0) {
    int rc = execv("command line program...", argv);
    }

// DO OTHER STUFF HERE. 

if (pid > 0) {
    waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
}
```

Is there any way to keep my main program running after the command line program dies abnormally? Thanks!

[UPDATE]:Yes, the main process is writing to a file where the command line is reading from, but it is a normal file, not a pipe. I receive a segfault.

It is extremely hard for me to reproduce the bug, since the child process does not crash very often. But it does happen. Randomly crashing is a known bug in the command line program, which is why I want to keep my main program alive even if the command line dies.

Comment: Based on what you posted I don't see why your main program would die.  Is this actually happening or something you are worried about happening?

Comment: Unless the parent and the child are interacting somehow, it is unlikely that the death of the child affects the parent process. Is the parent reading/writing from/to the child via a pipe? Are you getting a SIGPIPE signal perhaps? Or any other signal?

Comment: @Duck, yet it actually happens... So you think this is the right way of doing it?

Comment: @Luther Blissett: Thanks for your reply. Yes, the main process is writing to a file where the command line is reading from, but it is a normal file, not a pipe. I receive a segfault.

Comment: @usfish: are you using file locking?

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: no I am not. I updated my post to clarify the questions for a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your real code do you have an else here:

```
if (pid == 0) {
    int rc = execv("command line program...", argv);
    // possibly more child stuff
}
else {
    // parent stuff
}
```

It's always a good idea to post real code when asking questions here.

Answer (score 1):

- Use `vfork` rather than `fork` to avoid unnecessary process cloning.
- Make sure you don't crash when `SIGCHLD` is received by parent process.
- Use proper if-then-else statement to make it clear what code executes in parent process and what happens in a child process. For example it is very likely that both child and process will execute code where `// DO OTHER STUFF HERE.` comment is in case `execv` fails.
- After all, use `gdb`. It will tell you where the crash occurs.

Comment: I think it should still be noted that `vfork` does not exist on all unixoid systems according to APUE (Stevens, Rago), though it does on Linux and some other popular unixoid systems.

Comment: POSIX has `posix_spawn()` to replace `vfork()`.